# Why is phoneGap build only building for 3 platforms?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm building my first phoneGap app and compressed a zip file which includes my config.xml, index.html, index.css and index.js files. When I upload my zipfile it only shows 3 platforms to build for. How do I build for the others when all I need are those 3 core files? Currently it's only building for iOS, android and windows.

Below is a tree of all the files I compressed.

```
└── www
├── config.xml
├── css
│   └── index.css
├── img
│   └── logo.png
├── index.html
└── js
    └── index.js
```

Comment: Are you talking about PhoneGap Build? In that case, you can build locally for other platforms

Comment: Does PhoneGap Build mention an error? Normally it is very clear about why it isn't building for a particular platform.

Comment: Raymond: the OP asked why it is not building for other platforms (Blackberry, etc.)

Comment: @NicolasR but I thought with my zip file, the whole point is for me to use the code once, upload it and have phonegap build take care of the rest?

Comment: `PhoneGap Build` is just a tool around PhoneGap, to help build for some platforms, not all, sorry. Anyway, you can build all platforms locally, take a look at the CLI (Command Line Interface) in PhoneGap documentation

Comment: @NicolasR I went over the CLI documentation yesterday so I see where you are coming from, but I've seen some youtube videos of people uploading a zip file an it builds for more than 3 platforms so I was curious why this is happening?

Comment: I added an answer with the summary of my comments and a complement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used to send your project content to PhoneGapBuild website, in order to build your applications.

The current documentation is clear: [doc](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_supported_platforms.md.html#Supported%20Platforms)

```
Platforms = Android / iOS / Windows Phone 8
```

You can build other platforms locally, using CLI, and depending on your dev platform:

- iOS (Mac)
- Amazon Fire OS (Mac, Linux, Windows)
- Android (Mac, Linux, Windows)
- BlackBerry 10 (Mac, Linux, Windows)
- Windows Phone 7 (Windows)
- Windows Phone 8 (Windows)
- Windows 8 (Windows)
- Firefox OS (Mac, Linux, Windows)

See doc here: [phonegap CLI doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

Comment: No problem. Basically if I remember (but not 100% certain) PhoneGap build was able to build blackberry apps at a time, but not anymore

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap only provides automatic build for these platforms, but Cordova can be build locally to many other.

In that case you want to build to other platforms take care to review that plugins that you need are available or make them for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Intel XDK provides a similar service to Adobe's PhoneGap Build but supports a lot more platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap only provides automatic build for these platforms, but Cordova can be build locally to many other but you have to review that plugins that you need are available.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PhoneGap Build version 2.9.0 it supports more platforms.   http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/introduction_supported_platforms.md.html#Supported%20Platforms

Just add

```
<preference name="phonegap-version"           value="2.9.0" />
```

to your config.xml